# Trying to understand why power equation and ohm's law equation aren't agreeing

Tags: watts, ohms-law

Hobbyist EE-in-training here. I've been doing some simple problems to reinforce my knowledge of ohm's law and I've run into a snag -

> A stereo speaker has a resistance of 8.00 Ω. When it is operating at full power (exactly100 watts) it uses 35 volts of electricity. What is the current drawn by the speaker?

If I solve it using ohm's law with $$R = 8.00$$ and $$E = 35V$$

I get

$$\frac{35}{8.00} = 4.38A$$

and if I solve it with the power equation I get

$$\frac{100}{35} = 2.86A$$

Shouldn't these two equations agree?

Comment: The question is wrong. Where did it come from?

Comment: 100W into an 8ohm load requires 28.3V. Any higher voltage will dissipate more than 100W into 8 ohms. Like Matt says, the question is wrong.

Comment: If you Google "Ohm’s Law Practice Problems" it's the meridianschools result. I figured the problem was wrong. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Also, "35 volts of electricity" is a great way to cultivate a brain-damaged understanding of what "electricity" is. [What is Electricity?](http://amasci.com/miscon/whatis.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speakers are reactive; they exhibit impedance (a combination of resistance and reactance). So, right off the bat, the question isn't realistic.

Be that as it may, of course everything has to agree.  However, it is not clear what 35V means. We have to specify whether that is the amplitude, peak-to-peak value or RMS amplitude.

Usually we deal with wattages when it comes to speakers. RMS values for current and voltage, together with the average value for power, and the assumption of purely resistive loads, allow us to use the Ohm's Law formulas naively, as if we were dealing with DC.

If a 35V RMS AC signal is applied to purely resistive 8 ohm load, then the average power is \$V^2/R = 35\times 35 / 8 = 1225 / 8 = 153.1W\$.  The current is then \$153.1 / 35 = 4.38A\$.   This means that the resistor behaves like a 153W heater, exactly as if we put 35V DC on it.

If the load is not assumed to be purely resistive (and you're expected to know this and deal with it), then the use of the term "resistance" is wholly inappropriate in the question.

If the 35V figure is meant to be a peak amplitude, then that means the RMS figure is lower: it is \$0.707\times 35 \approx 24.75\$ which corresponds to only 76.5W average (half of 153.1).

Comment: A pedantic EE nitpick:  the product of rms voltage and rms current is average power, not rms power.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#Average_electrical_power

Comment: @AlfredCentauri That's hardly pedantic at all, and it's best if this is cleared up properly on this site. What 50W RMS means in an audio amplifier is clearly that if a resistor is hooked up, it's a 50W heater, which actually means average power, related to the RMS voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kaz: "speakers are reactive; they exhibit impedance (a combination of resistance and reactance)."

This is actually a pretty realistic question -- although perhaps unnecessarily tricky for schoolwork.
Most speakers are designed to have a DC resistance (as measured by an ohmmeter) of approximately 8 Ohms.
And yet the impedance of the speaker (when playing music)
is somewhat higher.
(The impedance often varies with frequency in a complex way,
and the various enclosures that a speaker can be mounted in also affect the impedance).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUAO9N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When working with audio, "the voltage" implies "the RMS voltage". "The current" implies "the RMS current".

Often people say that the RMS voltage is 0.707 times the peak voltage.
That's a pretty good approximation when working with single-phase AC power, but it isn't even close to true for the vast majority of the things normal humans listen to using speakers. So forget I even brought up peak voltage.

To find the current by Ohm's law,
we would calculate

I_rms = E_rms/Z = 35 V_rms / Z.

The impedance Z in this case is the impedance of the speaker inductance plus R1.
We know R1 is 8 Ohms, but we aren't given the impedance of the speaker inductance.
Sometimes we can approximate it as acting like a simple inductor, which has an impedance of 2*pi*f*L1.
But we aren't given L1.
Even if we were given L1, we don't know what the frequency f is.
We could *guess* that the frequency f is 0 Hz, but as you've seen, that leads to a contradiction.
So the frequency certainly *isn't* 0 Hz.
Since we're dealing with audio, it's almost certainly some complicated mixture of lots of different frequencies.

So we solve it with the power equation:

RMS_current = average_power / RMS_voltage

= 100 watt / 35 V_rms = 2.86 A_rms.

From this, we could derive the impedance:

Z = RMS_voltage / RMS_current

= 35 V_rms / 2.86 A_rms = 12.2 Ohm of impedance.

Of that, 5 ohms comes from the resistor, so the other 7.2 ohms must come from the speaker inductance.

I suppose you *could* plug that impedance into Ohm's law to calculate the current,
but that is going in circles -- you'll get exactly the same current we already calculated.

If hypothetically you knew that the "100 Watts" was being applied in the form of a simple sine wave at some frequency -- for example, 10 kHz -- then you could calculate the speaker inductance (at that frequency). For example, L1 = 7.2 Ohm / (2*pi*10kHz) = 115 uH.